# Problem  with name auto-complete when writing comments

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, comments

While writing comments as a reply to particular user, when i press @ followed by 1st letter of user's name i get an Auto-Complete box suggesting the user's name. It is a very useful feature.

But sometimes it doesn't work(even after retrying)? Why? Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you trying to reply to the author of the post, maybe? The author is always notified so it won't auto-complete (and it should get stripped out if you do it manually).

Comment: @eldarerathis  What do i do, if there are multiple comments for an answer and i want to reply to a particular comment ? (BTW, I know i can type the name manually)

Comment: If there are more than two commenters, @name should always work.  There's no mechanism for denoting which of two comments by the same commenter you're replying to, you just have to do it with words.

Answer (score 3):

It might save you some time spent writing these posts if you search the big parent Meta site, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/.  Questions there tagged "FAQ" may be particularly useful, e.g., [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)  That should cover this :)

Comment: i read that already.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're seeing one of two behaviours that changed recently with @replies. Essentially the @reply isn't auto-completed (and is often removed when you post) if there is only one possible, unmistakable person who's the target of your post and so your @name bit would be redundant.

So if you're making a comment on a question that has no answers, and it's the very first comment, then you are obviously making a comment to the questioner, so adding @name is redundant.

The other thing that's changed is that when SE thinks that two people are having a conversation (when there's only two of you commenting and you're going back and forth between you) then the @name is removed too, as it's obvious who you're talking to.

In these cases even though there's no @name in your comment, because it's obvious who you're talking to the person that you're talking to will still get notified that you're talking to them (for instance question askers are always notified when someone comments on their question with @naming anyone else).